# GET XML data in HTML page using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, database

I have been looking for getting XML data into my html page for few days now, and I still can't make it work.

I followed many tutorials, but I can't find the simplest way, to just dump xml data in an html page.

My XML data is generated by a php script.

```
<exemple>
<data> Hello</data>
<data> World</data>
</exemple>
```

I have seen people using all kind of tech, like angular.js, and long script, but I feel like things are to complicated for just a simple "print".

I know PHP and I would just do an include or an echo do to that.

The easiest script I found (but cannot make it work) was this one :

```
function showGetResult( )
    {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'localhost/test/test.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text/xml',
        success:function(data)
        {
          alert(data);
          document.write(data);
        }
      });
    }

showGetResult();
```

My question is :

Can I really hope to make work a script as simple as that ?
Angular js would help me if my whole app is getting data from database using php-xml-ajax ?

I'm very new to ajax, so please be indulgent. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since stackoverflow is a place where people thumb down a question posted 5 min ago because they think it's dumb. (actually the only forum i know where you are afraid to post dumb question), I asked somewhere else and I managed to make a working script. Here is it.

I load an txt file when you click on the button.

```
function submitForm1()
    {
        var req = null;
        document.getElementById("dyn1").value="Started...";
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e)
            {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }
        req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            document.getElementById("dyn1").value="Wait server...";
            if(req.readyState == 4)
            {
                if(req.status == 200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("dyn1").value=req.responseText;
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("dyn1").value="Error: returned status code " + req.status + " " + req.statusText;
                }
            }
        };
        req.open("GET", "helloworld.txt", true);
        req.send(null);
    }

</script>

<form name="ajax1" method="POST" action="">
    <p><input type="BUTTON" value="Envoyer" onclick="submitForm1()"></p>
    <p>Reçu:
        <input type="text" id="dyn1" size="32" value=""></p>
</form>
```